# Light in Blender Eevee shines through objects

Tags: lighting

I wanted to build a lamp in EEVEE, which should light the area but the light shines through the top of the cone, and I don´t know why.

[image: Picure with lighting bug]

Answer (score 0):

Select the light, go to it's properties, expand the *Shadow* menu, and enable *Contact Shadows*:

[image]